# Why are questions that involve langauge being shut down?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, questions

I recently had a question regarding language shut down as it was off topic. How is it that language isn't part of inter-personal skills?

Or is it more likely that the admin feared the response of an LGBT orientated questioned so they closed it down?

Here is the question under discussion:

[Seeking clarification on the use of "They/Them/Their" as a personal gender pronoun](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/23031/seeking-clarification-on-the-use-of-they-them-their-as-a-personal-gender-prono?noredirect=1#comment92695_23031)

Comment: Note that we have sister sites for languages: [english.se] (including its history and its quirk) and [linguistics.se] for more general linguistic topics.

Comment: @AndrewT. - Thank you for the links. I will post there. I have a feeling it will be deflected as it has been here.

Comment: David, how about you pause the quest for the answer for a little bit and see what's actually happening on this site or the other. You can also answer some questions if you'd like :)

Comment: @DavidGalea I'm afraid you have a misunderstanding on what Stack Exchange is really about; it's certainly not a "ask anything and get answered" Q&A site. Not all questions can be asked on SE, that's for sure. The community of each SE sites decides what kind of topics are on-topic or not. I only mention those sites since you look interested in the linguistic part of the issue, but I can't claim that it will be on-topic, or it's already asked.

Answer (score 21):

Your question is about language, not Interpersonal Skills. There are other sites on the network for questions about language, words, and what they mean. Those sites even take requests for specific words.

There have been numerous discussions in the past, and the outcome was simply that Interpersonal Skills are about the *behaviours* you use when interacting with other people, and that this site should *not* be used to give people advice on what to say. If you're struggling with *how* to say something, we may be of help. But if you're asking which word to use when, you're on the wrong site.

It doesn't matter whether you're looking for words to describe LGBT people, looking for a good word to label someone's behaviour or a word for a certain type of cutlery. This site is not the right one.

Answer (score 2):

Because the words themselves and the grammatical intricacies of using them are not the topic of this SE.

The linked question above is about whether or not is correct to use what was previously regarded as a third person plural pronoun as a gender-neutral third person single pronoun that refers to human beings (since the gender-neutral third person single pronoun "it" always refers to an object or non-sentient entity)

This is an English Language & Usage question and belongs in the corresponding SE.

If you wanted to ask about what is the proper way of addressing a LGBTQ+ correctly in a social setting, here would be the place. Please also note that the majority of those questions are also very language / region dependant   so the adequate tags need to be used.

A few examples of a good question would be:

> How to address a LGBTQ+ person if I don't know their gender orientation?

or

> I have a genderfluid colleague, how do I address them correctly?

Then proceed to give more details about the social setting and add the country tag.